# How to Access Remote Action From Test Class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, remote-action

How can I access a remote action from a test class? Here is what I have so far:

```
@remoteAction
public static Boolean createCaseRA(String newJCase,String prevCase){
    system.debug('Remote Prev Case>>>>'+prevCase);
    Case prevDTCase = new Case();
```

Comment: Please refrain from using all caps.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You call it like you would any other static method. If you are not sure how to begin writing unit tests, please work your way through the appropriate **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)** modules.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a remote action method is the same as accessing any other static method:

```
@isTest static void test() {
  // Set up your data first
  // Then...
  Test.startTest();
  String newJCaseParam = ..., prevCaseParam = ...;
  Boolean expectedResult = true, // or false, whatever you expect
    result = ClassName.createCaseRA(newJCaseParam, prevCaseParam);
  Test.stopTest();
  System.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
}
```